# ¿Porque no me carga los estilos del auth laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

¡Hola! , resulta que estoy usando laravel 9 y estoy cargando la plantilla de auth para registro y logeo de usarios , y resulta que no me cargan los estilos del boostrap , y no comprendo el porque , ya agregue los cdn pero no me resulta tampoco , muestro imágen y code del resultado,errores y estructuracion de carpetas, de antemano Muchas gracias !:

Aquí está la estructuracion de carpetas y el archivo app.blade.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructuracion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui está los errores por consola :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta lo que me muestra(cabe recalcar que funcionan las funcionalidades simplemente no me cargan los estilos) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui está el codigo de la primera imágen :

```php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            @if (Route::has('login'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif

                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por lo que veo tenés el CDN del JS de Bootstrap, pero no del CSS que es el que contiene los estilos.

Comment: Tenes razón no me di cuenta !, capa 8 , gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada tienes que revisar si tu proyecto esta utilizando vite (estoy 99% seguro que si), entonces tienes que utilizarlo para compilar app.css y app.js (aun no me queda claro como se puede hacer esto con vite ya que a mi no me ha funcionado), si quieres seguir utilizando webpack (que te lo recomiendo a pesar de ser mas lento) debes segir el tutorial https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix y cambiar

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

por

```
<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

habiendo compilado con webpack `npm run dev` o `npm run production`